# Problem with rcases*

Tags: math-mode, cases, mathtools

I want to put a right bracket because I need it, but it goes out of the page.

```
\[
\begin{rcases*}
\text{Si }f:\left[x_{1}, x_{2}\right]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\text{ es continua en } \left[x_{1}, x_{2}\right] \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\, f(x_{1}<f(x_{2})
\end{rcases*}\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\text{ tal que si }f(x_{1})<y<f(x_{2}),\,\exists x_{0}\in(x_{1},\,x_{2}):f(x_{0}):f(x_{0})\,=\,y
\]
```

[image]
(Grey part is the background of the pdf reader I use).

Also, if you how I can center the second line, I'll be very grateful with you.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I just stack the right-hand text with centered alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsfonts,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{rcases*}
\text{Si }f:\left[x_{1}, x_{2}\right]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\text{ es continua en } \left[x_{1}, x_{2}\right] \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\, f(x_{1}<f(x_{2})
\end{rcases*}
\stackanchor{\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\text{ tal que si }f(x_{1})<y<f(x_{2}),}
{\exists x_{0}\in(x_{1},\,x_{2}):f(x_{0}):f(x_{0})\,=\,y}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the OP prefers left or right alignment of the right-hand stack, that can be achieved with `\def\stackalignment{<l, or r>}` just inside the equation.  For example, here is an alternate presentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsfonts,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\def\stackalignment{r}
\begin{rcases*}
\text{Si }f:\left[x_{1}, x_{2}\right]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\text{ es continua en } \left[x_{1}, x_{2}\right] \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\, f(x_{1}<f(x_{2})
\end{rcases*}
\stackunder{\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\text{ tal que si }f(x_{1})<y<f(x_{2}),}
{\exists x_{0}\in(x_{1},\,x_{2}):f(x_{0}):f(x_{0})\,=\,y}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's simply wonderful! Thank you so much! It did the job as I want!

Answer (score 2):

Your equation without use of `rcases` and `stackengine`. Instead them I use two `aligned` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
    
    \begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \left.\begin{aligned}
\text{Si }f:[x_{1}, x_{2}]\to
    &\; \mathbb{R}\text{ es continua en } [x_{1}, x_{2}]    \\
    & f(x_{1})<f(x_{2})
    \end{aligned}\right\}\ 
\begin{aligned}
    &   \forall y\in\mathbb{R}\text{ tal que si }f(x_{1})<y<f(x_{2}),\\
    &   \exists x_{0}\in(x_{1},\,x_{2}):f(x_{0}):f(x_{0})=y
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]