# Cases in Farsi text

Tags: cases, xepersian

I want to use case in Farsi text.Something like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. You can use rcases with mathtools package (see the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248342/problem-with-rcases), but I not am familiar with the arabic (Farsi) language :-(.